# Stata: how to treat numerical values as categorical values in CEM?

Tags: stata, exact-match

In my data, I have a variable of income level, which is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 8, and 9. I am wondering if I directly put this variable in `imb` or `cem` without recoding as illustrated in the manual, will the algorithm treat is as numerical value or categorical value?

Or shall I do recoding like this

```
recode income (1 = 1 "1") (2 = 2 "2") (3 = 3 "3") (4 = 4 "4") (5 = 5 "5") (6 = 6 "6") (7 = 7 "7") (8 = 8 "8") (9 = 9 "9"), gen(income_recode)
```

I would like to apply exact match on categorical variable for my dataset.

Comment: There is no categorical value type in Stata. There are numeric type with and without value labels.

Comment: @TheIceBear Does that mean there is no way to do exact matching on "categorical" variable even after I do the recoding, convert it to numeric variables with value labels?

Comment: I do not know the specific commands you are referring to. It seems possible to do exact matching on any type of variable string or numeric. All I am saying that "categorical" or not will never matter as there is no such thing in Stata.